# Incorrect PHP/Contact Form Failing to function correctly

Tags: php, contact-form

So, I'm currently trying to code a contact form with the little knowledge of PHP that I have, and needless to say, it's failing miserably. I've searched the rest of the interwebs far and wide, and I haven't been able to get any answers solely by gleaning information off of forums.

Thus, I've come to you guys for help. Here is the form code:

```
                <form method="post" action="contactphp.php">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input name="firstname" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input name="lastname" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Company</label>
                    <input name="company" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Project</label>
                    <input name="project" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input name="city" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <select id="countries" name="country">
                        </select>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input name="phone" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Subject</label>
                    <input name="subject" placeholder="Type Here">
                    <label>Inquiry</label>
                    <textarea name="inquiry" placeholder="Please voice your inquiry(ies) here."></textarea>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </form>
```

I understand  needs s; I've omitted them because they list all of the countries in the world, which is a lot of pointless info regarding this question.

Here is the PHP code later down the page:

```
                <?php
                    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                    $company = $_POST['company'];
                    $project = $_POST['project'];
                    $city = $_POST['city'];
                    $country = $_POST['country'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                    $subject= $_POST['subject'];
                    $inquiry = $_POST['inquiry'];
                    $from = "From: $firstname $lastname representing $company";
                    $to = "dummyemail@gmail.com";
                    $subject= "INQUIRY, $subject";
                    $body = "From: $firstname $lastname\n Company: $company\n Project: $project\n City: $city, Country: $country\n Email: $email, Phone: $phone\n Message: \n $inquiry";

                    if ($_POST['submit']) {
                        if ($firstname === "" || $lastname === "" || $city === "" || $country === "NIL" || $email === "" || $phone === "" || $subject === "" || $inquiry === ""){
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
                             <p> Your message has been sent successfully!</p>
                            }
                            else{
                             <p>Your message has failed to send; please check all fields of the form to make sure it is filled out correctly.</p>
                            }

                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Again, if there is some blatantly stupid mistake, please forgive it; I'm only scraping together the syntax I know to form this script.

Also, if you answerers out there need any more info, please feel free to post about it.

Other info:

The server is currently outfitted with PHP 5.4.27, and is in working order (I downloaded a test page and tried using it; it logged all of the necessary info).

We're on a Linux box because Windows is SUPPOSEDLY less than adequate with file-permissions and whatnot (based on what I'm told).

Thanks for all of the help guys.

Comment: Why don't you use the empty() or isset() function (rather isset then empty but still...)??? also the FROM either has to a real existing mail OR totally empty

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: use var_dump($_POST) to see what all is being posted from form

Comment: `if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){?>
<p> Your message has been sent successfully!</p>
<?php }
else{
?> <p>Your message has failed to send; please check all fields of the form to make sure it is filled out correctly.</p>
<?php  }`

Answer (score 0):

Is your mail just not sending or are your `$_POST[]` variables not being populated? Either way, here are a couple possible solutions/debugging options:

First, Instead of checking the values via `if($firstname === '')` etc... I would do it as you are declaring the variables like:

`if(!isset($_POST['firstname'])) { 
    echo "Please enter your first name"; 
 } else { 
     $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
 }`

In your question, you said the PHP code you included is further down the page... your form `action` attribute is set to 'contactphp.php' ... if your PHP code is on the same page try setting the action attribute to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

As mentioned in a comment to the question, try using `var_dump($_POST);` to see what is being gathered from the `$_POST[]` submit.

Also, set PHP to display any errors by adding `ini_set('display_errors',1);` to the top of your document.

You could also try sending the mail via SMTP instead of PHPs `mail();` function.